# Why doesn't ethereum have a fast relay network like Bitcoin?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization, blocks, block-interval

I'm talking about nodes that miners connect to that help relay blocks fast, to reduce hash power wastage and forks:
http://bitcoinrelaynetwork.org/ and http://www.falcon-net.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in Ethereum you don't waste hashpower since stales are also rewarded.

A stale block is called *uncle* or *ommer block* in Ethereum and you might want to read about the reward scheme here: [What is GHOST and what is its relationship to Frontier and Casper?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/314/87)

And here: [What is an uncle/ommer block?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/34/87)

Comment: Adding a subtlety: you do waste *some* hash power as uncles are rewarded only 7/8 of the block reward and nephews only 1/32. This reduces the incentive for fast relay to 3-4x less (according to Vitalik Buterin).

Answer (score 2):

To supplement this with Vitalik's answer on Gitter (quoted):

1. Rewarding ommer blocks means miners have lesser incentive to mine on the latest block:

> basically means that miners' private incentive to make relaying
>   super-fast is ~3-4x lower than it normally would be this is by design,
>   to limit centralization concerns

2. Ethereum is computation-heavy. IO accesses and state Merkle root computation are more of a bottleneck than network latency. In Bitcoin, the transaction Merkle root can be precomputed (before getting the hash of the previous block).

> ethereum in practice is a bit more computation-heavy than bitcoin is,
>   though for reasons more subtle than "OMG it's turing complete!!1!", so
>   bandwidth improvements won't help quite as much 
>   the actual reasons are (i) you can't pre-compute as much before
>   receiving
>   the block as it's more order-dependent, (ii) there's overhead from
>   Merkle state root computations, (iii) you can't pre-compute IO
>   accesses as those may be dynamic