# Wastage with shorter block time and how it is handled

Tags: go-ethereum

Comparing to Bitcoin, Ethereum has much shorter block time. It is stated that Bitcoin has 10 minutes set to make least amount of wastage https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/why-was-the-target-block-time-chosen-to-be-10-minutes

I read in most places that Ghost protocol is implemented in Ethereum to solve this problem, but couldn't find how much wastage is going on. Then again it is said in some posts like here that  Ghost is not implemented in ethereum
[Why did Ethereum abandon the GHOST protocol?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38121/why-did-ethereum-abandon-the-ghost-protocol)
but Inclusive protocol. So my main question is how is it ok for Ethereum to have uncles and wastage and for bitcoin it isn't and how much of it has ethereum got?