# Are uncle blocks included in blockchain

Tags: uncle-blocks

When miners M1 and M2 compete to mine block B and miner M2 mines it just after miner M1, his mined block is called ommer/uncle/orphaned. 
I read that these blocks (untill sixth generation) can be included in the blockchain. Does this mean that transactions of block B are included twice?

Comment: Related https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13378/what-is-the-exact-longest-chain-rule-implemented-in-the-ethereum-homestead-p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Only uncle block headers are included. Also when including uncles only the validity of their headers is checked, transactions are ignored. From [Design Rationale](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Design-Rationale):

> Uncle validity requirements: uncles have to be valid headers, not valid blocks. This is done for simplicity, and to maintain the model of a blockchain as being a linear data structure (and not a block-DAG, as in Sompolinsky and Zohar's newer models). Requiring uncles to be valid blocks is also a valid approach.