# How do mrand.Float64() output the same result with same order in reorganisation?

Tags: consensus, randomness

Recently, I did go deep into the code of reorganisation in blockchain, but I'm confused by the `mrand.Float64()` in `WriteBlockWithState`. Here is the code: [original code position](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/blockchain.go#L963)

```
// If the total difficulty is higher than our known, add it to the canonical chain
// Second clause in the if statement reduces the vulnerability to selfish mining.
// Please refer to http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~ie53/publications/btcProcFC.pdf
reorg := externTd.Cmp(localTd) > 0
currentBlock = bc.CurrentBlock()
if !reorg && externTd.Cmp(localTd) == 0 {
    // Split same-difficulty blocks by number, then at random
    reorg = block.NumberU64() < currentBlock.NumberU64() || (block.NumberU64() == currentBlock.NumberU64() && mrand.Float64() < 0.5)
}
```

I know when system receive a block getting the same total difficult and same height, it will use `mrand.Float64()` to get a "random" number between 0-1 to decide whether reorg or not. My question is how will it ensure different geth client will get the same result by this? I mean, the geth client can start at different time and may execute `mrand.Float64()` different times, hence get different result and different chain. Am I missing something? Please help!

Comment: An answer here states that ties are resolved randomly https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/13750. If you have two blocks with the same difficulty you can choose either to be fair with both miners it is better to let the network decide with the next block.

Comment: Thanks for your response first. I check the link, but the reason why the random number can get the same result is not clarity; Considering this situation:
A and B on block height 50 get a tie and hence execute the `mrand.Float64()`, on block height 150 B stoped and restart from last known head block(after 50 block) while A not. Then on block height 200, they receive a tie and have to execute `mrand.Float64()` one more time. but this is the second time A excute and first time B excute becasue of restart. So may get different result. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, every node will choose a different random number, in theory half of the network will choose one value and the other half the other (the exact proportion is 50% because of the delay in network propagation). The ties do not last very long if nodes A and B separate at block 50, then after a few blocks one of them will be in the majority fork and the other will have to switch to the majority fork as soon as possible.